# Kafka: MirrorMaker 2 result

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I'm running through some use cases for kafka mirror maker 2.  I have it running in distributed mode at the moment and replication 'appeared' to be running but the result on the target cluster doesn't match the source.

my distributed prop file has the following.  My distributed prop file has my target cluster.  I'm pretty sure this is correct because when I had it set to the source cluster, it would create the replicated topic on the source cluster

```
bootstrap.servers=**target-cluster:9092**
name=mm2-distributor
group.id=mm2-connect-cluster
client.id=mm2-client-id
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
...
...
rest.port=8083
```

my source-connector.json file has the following:

```
{
    "name": "mm2-connect-cluster",
    "config":{
    "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector",
        "name": "mm2-connect-cluster",
        "group.id": "mm2-connect-cluster",
        "client.id": "mm2-client-id",
        "topics": "test.*",
        "tasks.max": "8",
        "source.cluster.alias": "source",
        "target.cluster.alias": "target",
        "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "source-cluster:9092",
        "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "target-cluster:9092",
        "source->target.enabled": "true",
        "target->source.enabled": "false",
        "offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor": "4",
        "topics.blacklist": ".*[\\-\\.]internal, .*\\.replica, __consumer_offsets",
        "groups.blacklist": "console-consumer-.*, connect-.*, __.*",
        "topic.creation.enabled": "true",
        "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": "4",
        "topic.creation.default.partitions": "25"
    }
}
```

After starting the distributor and REST call, I started sending some test messages to the `test` topic.  The source look like this:

[image: messages @ source]

The target side messages aren't matching the source and look like this:

[image: messages @ target]

I'm curious if this is the expected result and if so, how would I go about getting it display the message correctly?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not all your messages are JSON, so that's a sign you're using the wrong converter

If you wish to transfer the messages as-is, you don't need conversion, so you should use the BytesConverter for both key and value

The reason you're seeing the "schema" field is because you've set `schemas.enable=true`. If you expand the columns and look into the "payload", though, you should see they do match